# How can i find list of all the table in database with contain atlease one record on it. which means have some data in tables.

Tags: sql-query-store

i would like help with sql query which can find list of all table in  a database which contain some data in it. just list of table with data excluding all the tables with no data on it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can query the "information schema", however the numbers are only estimates, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_ROWS > 0 OR DATA_LENGTH > 0
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention i am trying this on mssql and we dont have table_rows column in there

Comment: found the answer fortunately thank you FOR your HELP 
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS [SchemaName],
[Tables].name AS [TableName],
SUM([Partitions].[rows]) AS [TotalRowCount]
FROM sys.tables AS [Tables]
JOIN sys.partitions AS [Partitions]
ON [Tables].[object_id] = [Partitions].[object_id]
AND [Partitions].index_id IN ( 0, 1 )
-- [Tables].name = N'name of the table'
GROUP BY SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), [Tables].name
HAVING  (SUM(Partitions.rows)) > 0